# i am tring to implement OnScrollListener to recyclerview but there is error in code see dertails below

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

nothing was happening while running app after scrolling to bottom there is no loading sign of loading data below is endlessScroll code extending RecyclerView.OnScrollListener

```
public abstract class EndlessScroll extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {
public static String TAG = EndlessScroll.class.getSimpleName();

private int previousTotal = 0; // The total number of items in the dataset after the last load
private boolean loading = true; // True if we are still waiting for the last set of data to load.
private int visibleThreshold = 4; // The minimum amount of items to have below your current scroll position before loading more.
int firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;

private int current_page = 1;

private LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager;

public EndlessScroll(LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager) {
    this.mLinearLayoutManager = linearLayoutManager;
}

@Override
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

    visibleItemCount = recyclerView.getChildCount();
    totalItemCount = mLinearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
    firstVisibleItem = mLinearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

    if (loading) {
        if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
            loading = false;
            previousTotal = totalItemCount;
        }
    }
    if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount)
            <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
        // End has been reached

        // Do something
        current_page++;

        onLoadMore(current_page);

        loading = true;
    }
}

public abstract void onLoadMore(int current_page);
```

}

and now below is my async task code

```
public class RequestItems extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
Context context;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
List<ParseObject> parseObjects;
List<FeedItem> feedItems=new ArrayList<>();
EventsRecyclerView eventsRecyclerView;
RecyclerView recyclerView;





RequestItems(Context context,RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    this.context = context;
    this.recyclerView=recyclerView;

}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading");
    progressDialog.show();
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    Loadmore();
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    final EventsRecyclerView eventsRecyclerView=new EventsRecyclerView(context,feedItems);
    int spacingInPixels = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.spacing);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SpacesItemDecoration(spacingInPixels));
    LinearLayoutManager manager=new LinearLayoutManager(context);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
    recyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessScroll(manager) {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore(int current_page) {
           Loadmore();
        }
    });

    recyclerView.setAdapter(eventsRecyclerView);

}

private void Loadmore() {
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Events");
    query.setLimit(5);
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt");
    try {
        parseObjects = query.find();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (!parseObjects.isEmpty()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < parseObjects.size(); i++) {
            FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
            item.setTitle(parseObjects.get(i).getString("Title"));
            item.setDate(parseObjects.get(i).getString("Date"));
            item.setTime(parseObjects.get(i).getString("Time"));
            item.setVenue(parseObjects.get(i).getString("Venue"));
            item.setLike(parseObjects.get(i).getBoolean("Like"));
            ParseFile file = parseObjects.get(i).getParseFile("EventImage");
            try {
                byte bytes[] = file.getData();
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                Bitmap bitmap1 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,150,200,true);
                item.setEventImage(bitmap1);
                feedItems.add(item);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


}
```

}
i am not able to find error in this code is there something missing or wrong

Comment: I don't see the dertails!

Comment: sir i am week in english please use simple words

Comment: I'm just playing with you. You misspelled details.

Comment: It is not quite clear what error are you facing and what you are trying to achieve. Please add stack trace if your have error or describe problem more specifically if your code compiles, but does not work as it should

Comment: oh sorry for that ,this happened because my mind is running crezy cause am not able to do this onscrollistener

Comment: there is no stack trase error but when i am scrolling down to bottem of list it dose not loading more items to recyclerview list

Answer (score -1):

try below method instead

```
GroomViewAdapter groomViewPagerAdapter = new GroomViewAdapter(getBaseContext(), 
listGroom,R.layout.item_groom_viewpager);
    viewpagerGroom.setAdapter(groomViewPagerAdapter);
viewpagerGroom.clearOnScrollListeners();
    viewpagerGroom.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener(){

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            if(dy < 100){
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, 0);
            }else {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            }
        }


    });
```